# Responsive resizing image-height to fit text-div next to it

Tags: html, css

Im creating a two colum website, having to fit pictures next to text-boxes. The images have to resize according to the text-divs, so that they at all time cover 50% width each, and the height is defined by the div containing the text. (Eg. imagine pulling the window to lesser width, the text will fill more in height, and the image will have to fill the same height, and still be centered in its container and keep its aspect-ratio.)
Is this possible using only HTML and CSS, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine the table solution with the background-size: cover; solution.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/64gzjah4/2/

**CSS:**

```
td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
}
td:first-child {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/300');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; /* Make the image cover the td */
    background-position: 50% /* Center the image inside the td */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            Text goes here
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What browser support do you need? IE8 does not support the background-size property, but the property is perfect for what you need, so hopefully you don't need support for IE8 ;) http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaand it's perfect! I don't think i'll need to support IE8. Hopefully not. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use flexbox for that (if I understand what you want to achieve correctly :) ).

See demo at https://jsfiddle.net/64gzjah4/1/

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch; /* Align height */
}
.item {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
}
.item:first-child {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/300');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; /* Make the image cover the div */
    background-position: 50% /* Center the image inside the div */ 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       Text goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the browser support for flexbox is not that good, so it depends on you browser requirements. The browser support for flexbox (as well as a guide for flexbox) can be seen at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I need some degree of backwards compatibility, therefore i'm not sure flexbox would do the trick. But thank you for a nice suggestion. :)
Also, you have understood it perfectly and given a nice visual example. But a solution with better backward compatibility would be preferred.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1** is to use the answer provided by Heidi Selmer Nielsen, however as mentioned Flexboxes don't offer great support and they don't cover the scenario you've mentioned entirely in your question.

> image will have to fill the same height, and still be centered in its container and keep its aspect-ratio

**Solution 2** is to use tables (i know i said it right, TABLES?!) They don't do exactly what you want but you will keep the aspect ratio of the image, however you can't control the height by the text cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/cved0fwh/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="img"><img src="http://data3.whicdn.com/images/20161286/large.jpg" /></td>
    <td class="txt">Odd Future Intelligentsia gentrify, Thundercats McSweeney's meh kitsch narwhal leggings. Gastropub pop-up twee drinking vinegar. Lomo Blue Bottle meditation, migas VHS listicle leggings. XOXO bitters ethical actually. Fap kitsch Intelligentsia, locavore chia Bushwick roof party ennui four loko skateboard messenger bag art party mixtape iPhone taxidermy. Chillwave artisan put a bird on it Blue Bottle cred. Forage tilde tote bag vinyl listicle skateboard Austin deep v chambray church-key.  Odd Future Intelligentsia gentrify, Thundercats McSweeney's meh kitsch narwhal leggings. Gastropub pop-up twee drinking vinegar. Lomo Blue Bottle meditation, migas VHS listicle leggings. XOXO bitters ethical actually. Fap kitsch Intelligentsia, locavore chia Bushwick roof party ennui four loko skateboard messenger bag art party mixtape iPhone taxidermy. Chillwave artisan put a bird on it Blue Bottle cred. Forage tilde tote bag vinyl listicle skateboard Austin deep v chambray church-key.</td>
</tr>
```

```
tr{
    border:1px solid red;
}
td {
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
}
img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

**Solution 3**

And the only way to achieve the effect you're looking for is to use a client side scripting language like Javascript.

http://jsbin.com/xuputulodu/edit?js,output

I've just thrown together a quick and dirty proof of concept for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function imageSize(){
    var a = $('img').height();
    var b = $('.text').height();

    if (a > b){
      $('img').height(b).width('auto').css('margin-top', 0);
    } else if (b > a){
      $('img').width('100%').height('auto').css('margin-top', (b-a)/2);
    }
  }

  $(window).resize(function(){
    imageSize();    
  });

});
```

Comment: Also I recommend you look at https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: The image must at all times cover the entire width and height of its container, since i have some "funky" overlays, that are arranged around the corners. Thank you for a nice suggestion though. I can add, that the picture is allowed to overflow the container, but must fill it and keep its ratio and stay centred.